# "by the time" and past simple

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

In a museum I saw this sentence, I was a bit surprised

> By the time the letter was posted, the children **were** already dead.

Is it correct? I would write *The children **had been** dead*.

What is the difference between these two apart tenses used?

Answer (score 1):

By the time the letter was posted, the children were already dead.

There's nothing wrong grammatically with this sentence. You usually use the linking verb in front of an adjective instead of "had been" in such sentences.  However, if you are using the verb "die" in the sentence, you can say ".............the children had already died". Look at the following sentences:

1. By the time I went to bed, I was exhausted (The Free DIctionary).
2. By the time we got home, we were tired and hungry (Longman).

Comment: Why does it work for die and not dead. Is it because dead are a state and not an action?

Comment: When using Perfect Tenses with/for the verb "to be", it seems necessary to give the period for which the state was known/appeared to exist.  In this example, "**had been** dead (for how long? - missing)".  I am not sure about this, thought, but that's what my mind is searching for when reading "have been so and so" or "had been so and so".

Comment: user5577,  I think you can also use "had been dead'"  instead of  "were dead" that's more usual.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use ***were dead*** because they indeed were still dead at the same time. It's simple logic here: same time = same tense. Of course they **had died** (earlier) but that's a single action that in fact took place before the letter was posted. To use '*had been dead*' it would make more sense to include the amount of time they had been in that state which would extend it to the time before the mailing of the letter.